# Raspberry Pi Zero W and PowerBoost 500

Tags: power, pi-zero

I recently bought a PowerBoost 500 Basic, and I would like to know if it's enough to power a Raspberry Pi Zero W, running RetroPie or Recalbox, or if I need to switch on a PowerBoost 1000c.
Also, can I still use the Basic PowerBoost to recharge my battery?
Thanks.

Comment: The Zero W uses about 240ma at most. The Powerboost 500 can output 500ma. So yes, it should work. The Powerboost 1000 can charge batteries not the 500. This is fairly easy to google....

Comment: Adafruits powerboost 1000 basic provides 1000 mA current, only the powerboost 1000C is capable of charging LiPos. There's also a powerboost 500C available.